# How to select data rows

Tags: python, select, rows

I have a 4 columns x 180.000 rows data file. I'd like to select entire rows of data to be saved to a new file, based on the criterion that the value in column 3 is within a specific interval, i.e. min value < column 3 value < max value.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You could have Python execute a SQL statement that does this insert of rows into the other table.  Read up on how Python can communicate with SQL databases. Your actual conditional criteria are not very clearly expressed by the way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the file in a format that suits the `csv` module?

Comment: @Tim: No need to use SQL if this needs to be written out to a new file. You'd need to read the whole file *anyway*, so you may as well just filter row by row and write out the matching rows.

Comment: what kind of data file is it? a csv?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: When I saw "rows and columns" and "any ideas" in the question and "data" and "select" tags, I thought of a database rather than CSV text file. Of course SQL is never required; and I did write "could" not "must". But why not use a bona fide database such as SQLite? SQL set operations are powerful! :-) http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read and write, then just filter:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as inputfile, open(outputfile, 'wb') as outputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)

    for row in reader:
        if minval <= int(row[2]) <= maxval:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: this would work great, but isn't it possible that the format of his data will not work with the csv module.

Comment: The possibility is there, but given that the OP knows it's 4 columns throughout the file chances are that it'll work. The answer is easily adjusted to most formats, and otherwise a quick `.split(..)` with perhaps some stripping does the trick for 99% of the remainder.

Comment: that's true. You also might need to add a delimiter depending on how the csv is formatted anyways. I guess we'll just have to wait for some more information.

Comment: Exactly. I included a link to the module documentation, so *hopefully* that will be looked at as well. The module is easy enough to use.

Comment: in 3rd line shouldn't it be "outputfile" instead of "inputfile"?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with simple CSV Read/ Write.
Can be done more elegantly and in a vectorized form using Numpy and moreover since the number of rows is huge, Numpy might get be a lot quicker.

```
import numpy as np
#Load file into a 'MATRIX'
data=np.loadtxt('name_of_delimited_file.txt')
# Find indices where the condition is met
idx_condition_met=(data[:,2] > min) & (data[:,2] < max)
np.savetxt('output.txt', data[idx_condition_met], delimiter=',')
```